# Error: Call to a member function setPayrollperiodid() on null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to count the number of payroll week that matches the payroll period entered. It returns the correct number but won't add to the database but instead says there's no match in the database. When I make changes I get this error:

> Error: Call to a member function setPayrollperiodid() on null.

I have outlined what I have thus far. Can someone tell me where I went wrong.

I have made some updates to the question I no longer get that error but record isn't adding instead it's saying that it doesn't match where did I go wrong in the controller.

### Repository

```
class PayrollweekRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)
    {
        $repository = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek');

        $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('pw');
        $qb->select('pw');
        $qb->where('pw.startdate=:startdate');
        $qb->Andwhere('pw.enddate=:enddate');
        $qb->setParameter('startdate', $startdate);
        $qb->setParameter('enddate', $enddate);
        $qb->getquery()->getResult();
    }

    public function countBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)
    {
        $repository = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek');

        $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('pw');
        $qb->select('count(pw.id)');
        $qb->where('pw.startdate=:startdate or pw.enddate=:enddate');
        $qb->setParameter('startdate', $startdate);
        $qb->setParameter('enddate', $enddate);

        $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

        var_dump($count);
        return $count;
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Payrollperiod();

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {   
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $payrollperiod = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')
            ->findOneBy([
                'startdate' => $form->get('startDate')->getData(),
                'enddate' => $form->get('endDate')->getData()]
            );

        $payrollweek = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')
            ->findBystartdateAndenddate($entity->getStartDate() , $entity->getEndDate());

        $counter = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')
            ->countBystartdateAndenddate($entity->getStartDate() , $entity->getEndDate());

        //If entity exists
        if ($payrollperiod){
            $this->addFlash('error', 'Error: A payroll period is already present with the same start and end date.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
        }
        //If PayrollWeek matches the Payrollperiod entered
        elseif ( $counter==2){
           $payrollweek->setPayrollperiodid($entity); 
        }

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Payroll Period was added.');
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Payroll week was updated.');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
        //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_show', array('payrollperiodid' => $entity->getpayrollperiodid())));
    }
    else{
        $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period does not match a payroll week.');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));  
    }

    //return $this->render('comtwclagripayrollBundle::new.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView()));
    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );   
}
```

**UPDATES**

```
public function countBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)
{
    $repository = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek');

    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('pw');
    $qb->select('count(pw.id)');
    $qb->where('pw.startdate=:startdate or pw.enddate=:enddate');
    $qb->setParameter('startdate', $startdate);
    $qb->setParameter('enddate', $enddate);

    $count = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    var_dump($count);
    return $count;
}

public function createAction(Request $request)
{


    $entity = new Payrollperiod();

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $payrollperiod = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->findOneBy(['startdate'=>$form->get('startDate')->getData(), 'enddate'=>$form->get('endDate')->getData()]);

        //$payrollweek = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')->findBystartdateAndenddate($form->get('startDate')->getData(), $form->get('endDate')->getData());

        $counter = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')->countBystartdateAndenddate($form->get('startDate')->getData(), $form->get('endDate')->getData());


        //If entity exists
        if ($payrollperiod){
                $this->addFlash('error', 'Error: A payroll period is already present with the same start and end date.');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
            }
            //If PayrollWeek matches the Payrollperiod entered
           elseif ($counter==2){
            foreach ($counter as $pWeek) {

                $pWeek->setPayrollperiodid($entity); 

            }

          $em->persist($entity);
          $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Payroll Period was added.');
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Payroll week was updated.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
           //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_show', array('payrollperiodid' => $entity->getpayrollperiodid())));
             }
             else{
               $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period does not match a payroll week.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));  
             }
       }

       //return $this->render('comtwclagripayrollBundle::new.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView()));
       return array(
           'entity' => $entity,
           'form'   => $form->createView(),
       );   

        }
```

**Further Updates**

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{


    $entity = new Payrollperiod();

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $payrollperiod = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->findOneBy(['startdate'=>$form->get('startDate')->getData(), 'enddate'=>$form->get('endDate')->getData()]);

        $payrollweek = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')->findBystartdateAndenddate($form->get('startDate')->getData(), $form->get('endDate')->getData());



        //If entity exists
            if ($payrollperiod){
                    $this->addFlash('error', 'Error: A payroll period is already present with the same start and end date.');
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
                }
            //If PayrollWeek matches the Payrollperiod entered
            elseif ($payrollweek){  
            $count = count($payrollweek);
            foreach ($payrollweek as $pWeek) {
            $pWeek->setPayrollperiodid($entity); 
            } 

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Payroll Period was added.');
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Payroll week was updated.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
           //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_show', array('payrollperiodid' => $entity->getpayrollperiodid())));
             }
             else{
               $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period does not match a payroll week.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));  
             }
}



       //return $this->render('comtwclagripayrollBundle::new.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView()));
       return array(
           'entity' => $entity,
           'form'   => $form->createView(),
       );   

        }
```

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: no i did not resolve it

Comment: maybe `$em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')->findBystartdateAndenddate($entity->getStartDate() , $entity->getEndDate());` returns null ??

Comment: yeah that's what I see but i'm not getting why if there's a match it wouldn't add to the database

Comment: You can't do the `foreach` on `$counter` because `$counter` is a single integer value.

Comment: Yeah I made the changes but it still giving a does not match error

Comment: You should get rid of your `countBystartdateAndenddate()` function and get the other one to work properly with your `OR`.

Comment: So would I count the information retrieved

Comment: I get the other function to work with the OR but I want to count the results returned

Comment: Yes, that is very simple.  Have your `$payrollweek = ...;` as normal, and then do `$counter = count($payrollweek);`

Comment: Then I can say if counter==2. Or that's too much ifs in the controller? When I use another if it just reload the page nothing doesn't happen

Comment: You can use it in the controller.  I mean there's always room to refactor things later but I would focus on getting it working first.

Comment: I have tried using it in the controller but it doesn't work

Comment: The function findBystartdateAndenddate works, it just the part about the count.

Comment: Can you show me how that would go in the controller

Comment: I updated my answer, have a look.

Comment: the looping caused it loop back and give the error that the start date and end date already exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151920/discussion-between-jason-roman-and-sue).

Comment: Hey Jason i'm having a little issue with a question can you assist please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not checking that `$payrollweek` exists before trying to use it.  In your case, it didn't find a value when you ran this function:

```
$payrollweeks = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')
    ->findBystartdateAndenddate($entity->getStartDate() , $entity->getEndDate());
```

Since it didn't find anything, `$payrollweek` is `NULL` instead of an instance of your **Payrollweek** entity.  You could add another check like this:

```
if (!$payrollweeks) {
    $this->addFlash(
        'error',
        'Error: No payroll week found with the given start and end date'
    );

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
}
```

**EDIT** based on discussions:

You should be able to get rid of your `countBystartdateAndenddate()` function and just use PHP's [count()](http://php.net/count) function to get the results you want, then loop over your payroll weeks:

```
$count = count($payrollweeks);

foreach ($payrollweeks as $payrollweek) {
    $payrollweek->setPayrollperiodid($entity); 
}
```

Comment: So if there's a match why would I get the error that there's no match

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When I do the count it returns 2 which suggest there's a match but it won't add the records to the table

Comment: It's because your first `findBy()` uses `AND` and your count uses `OR` so just because you get 2 results returned doesn't mean that `$payrollweek` isn't going to be `NULL`

Comment: Yeah I just realized that's the issue

Comment: I have changed it to OR but it still telling me that there's no match, maybe I did something wrong in the controller

Comment: I'd have to see what you changed it to.  You also don't need both queries.  You only need the normal one that returns information, and then you can do a PHP `count()` on what is returned there.

Comment: So the second query would do the count on what is returned

Comment: Your code makes less sense after the update.  That `while()` statement is going to give you an infinite loop.  I'd advise just playing around with the code a bit and then if you come across a new issue ask something specific to that.

Comment: Ok I get another the setpayrollperiod on array

Comment: the count query I was referring to as you said I should do a count on the info returned

Comment: Hey Jason even with using an OR, I'm not getting a match

Comment: I have updated what I have..its looping back to the point it says that the date already exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151921/discussion-between-sue-and-jason-roman).

Comment: Hey Jason I'm asking if you could take a look at a solution for me please